# How would you unit test a timer?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm looking for an example of how you would go about unit testing a timer inside of C#..

My timer code:

```
    public Timer(TimeSpan interval)
    {
        Interval = interval;

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer(Interval.TotalMilliseconds);
        timer.Elapsed += TimerElapsed;

        stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    }
```

Comment: What is `TimerElapsed`? Does that fire an event your unit test code could subscribe to?

Comment: Wrap System.Timers.Timer in an interface and mock it

Comment: This is not a duplicate.  The question marked as a duplicate is about a unit test that uses a timer.  This is about unit testing a timer itself.